# Wiring a garage door sensor

Tags: led, light

Looking to wire an LED light indicator for my garage door. I'm in no way a lighting/electrical expert and I could use help. I do repair copiers for a living. Home auto mechanic rebuild motors etc. I have replace the entire house with new receptacles. I am a tech and work on electrical things here and there.

Here is what I need help on. I am wiring a sensor so that when the garage door opens a Led light will come on in the house to let me know that its open.

This is what I have:

1. Transformer/ power supply input 100-24v,output 9v-500mA
2. 3mm Pre-wired LED Red Emitting Diode DC 9-12V 620-630nm Voltage(V) 20ma
3. Door Contact Magnetic Reed Switch closed. Max. Current: 0.5A Max. Voltage: 100V DC Max. Power: 10W
4. 40 feet of wire

Do I need any resistor for this? or will it work fine with out it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a circuit drawing?

Comment: It looks like there is a resistor under the heat shrink tubing.  If you wire it up directly to the transformer does it light up or blow out?  (I'm thinking it'll blow out).   They're cheap.

Comment: I have not receive it yet. I have the power supply so far

Comment: This is all the info on this led I have at the moment.   Red Pre-wired Diffused LED:  DC 9-12V 620-630nm   I think the last few numbers are Dominant Wavelength

Comment: I just fount out the resister is It's 470ohm.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a plain LED, you would need a current limiting resistor.  However if you use an LED panel mount pilot light, it will be as simple as drilling a hole in a faceplate and hooking up the leads.

Comment: Not sure if that is a resister in there already. I'm asking supplier

Comment: I see you added a picture, that sure looks like a resistor in the shrink tubing on that pre-wired LED.  Still for just a couple bucks it might be worth buying a pilot light so it's easy to mount.

Comment: No room for a pilot light. Just enough for the led.

Comment: Anyone have any Ideas on this?